# Print statements within Java stored procedures

Tags: java, oracle, java-stored-procedures

I am trying to add print statements to my oracle java stored procedure just to debug it (because I am not getting the required results from it) and see how it is progressing.
When I add System.out.println statement and execute it from SQL developer, it is not printing anything either in my Script Output pane or Messages or Logging panes.

Could someone who has already worked in this help me with information on which statement I have to use to add the print statements to my java proc and where it will be printed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: from stored procedure return out parameter

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14187/chthree.htm#CACIIEDH offers the following help. When implementing this in SQL Developer, these statements would appear above your call to your Java Stored Procedure (or whatever PLSQL code is wrapping it):

**Redirecting Output on the Server**

System.out and System.err print to the current trace files. To redirect the output to the SQL*Plus text buffer, use the following workaround:

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

SQL> CALL dbms_java.set_output(2000);
```

The minimum and default buffer size is 2,000 bytes and the maximum size is 1,000,000 bytes. In the following example, the buffer size is increased to 5,000 bytes:

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 5000

SQL> CALL dbms_java.set_output(5000);
```

The output is printed at the end of the call.